# Nous sommes champions d'Europe

Tags: grammaire

Why we say

> Nous sommes champions **d'Europe**

and not

> Nous sommes les champions **de l'Europe**

It comes from Paris Match Article. It was a quotation.

Can I use **d'Europe** and **de l'Europe** in the same way?

Comment: We could say, Nous sommes les champions de l'Europe. But note the plural of "les".

Comment: So both versions are ok?

Comment: Your second sentence lacks an 's' just before "champions". Nous sommes LES champions de l'Europe.

Comment: Ok I know but can we use d'Europe and de l'Europe on same meanings? Or it is something different?

Comment: It can be use interchangeably. But Europe can have different meanings depending on the context.

Comment: Can you explain me these contexts?

Comment: Europe can mean the continent of Europe but can also mean the European Union. Through time, the European Union changes, so depending on the dates, you can be talking about different country groups.

Comment: @Kii  "Nous sommes les champions de l'Europe" doesn't sound natural at all and should definitively not be used in this context.

However, one would say "Nous sommes les fondateurs de l’Europe" and not "Nous sommes les fondateurs d’Europe" to signify "We are the founders of Europe"

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following forms are idiomatic and equivalent, although the first one would be more natural:

> Nous sommes champions d'Europe.
>
> Nous sommes les champions d'Europe.

That one is not:

> Nous sommes les champions de l'Europe

unless used with *champion* meaning "someone who fight to defend a cause", but this acception is outdated.